# How to quickly rename an object in 2.8+ (like with the Item section in 2.79)

Tags: interface, data-blocks

In 2.79 there was an "**Item**" section in the Properties Panel that allowed the active object to be renamed quickly any time.

[image]

This made it easy to label objects quickly, so keeping an organized nicely labeled .blend file was no biggie.

In 2.8+ however, I can't find that section, or any other part of the UI where an object's name can be double-clicked and quickly renamed - except the Outliner.

Using the Outliner for that is fine *when the .blend is small and there are only a few objects*, but once you have more complexity and are dealing with nested parent-child hierarchies you may not be able to see the active object in the Outliner without drilling down. At which point one is tempted to start thinking "ah, forget it... maybe *'Cube.036'* is descriptive enough". But that's not really exercising best practices, and cutting corners in the short-term can cost time in the long-term if data is too disorganized.

Is there perhaps **a similar way to quickly rename objects in 2.8+** that I am unaware of? If there is, I'd like to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the <kbd>F2</kbd> key after selecting the desired object either in the *3D View* or in the *Outliner*.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the name from the properties panel, you can do it from the Object Properties tab:

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm sorry - I neglected to mention that I am aware of this method too. It can be quicker than the Outliner. Apoorv's answer is precisely what I was after, but I appreciate you taking the time to contribute an answer. It may be helpful for others!